# Is “better off together” means better together or better not together?

Tags: phrase-usage

Can I just write “We both are better off together” instead of “I am better off without him” or do the sentences speak different meanings as well?

Comment: 'better off' is an idiom that you can find in a dictionary. It means almost the same as 'better'.  Here is a link to a dictionary definition https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/better-off

Comment: Voting to close as it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: *Together* and *apart / without / not together* mean opposite things. You can't say the opposite of what you mean and expect it to mean the same thing that you mean. So, this question is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

"Better off" means "in a more satisfactory situation". “We both are better off together” and “I am better off without him” have practically opposite meanings. The first means that it is more satisfactory for both of you to be together than apart, and the second means it would be more satisfactory for you to be without him than with him.

Did you mean “We both are better off apart” for the first sentence? if so, the difference is that the first sentence speaks of what would be better for both of you, and the second only speaks of what would be better for you.

Comment: So it’s the same as “We both are better off without each other”?

Comment: Did you mean  “We both are better off **together**” or " “We both are better off **apart**” for your first question? They mean opposite things. Please answer this question.

Comment: Even it sounds like they were bad if together when it’s just they got nothing from each other, well I guess yes. Kind of.

Answer (score 2):

The meanings are certainly different.

If you say to someone "We are better off together" you mean that you want to work/live/ or whatever together. That is the complete opposite of saying "I am better off without them", about that person, because it means that you do not want to have anything to do with that person.

Your first sentence includes the word "both". If you mean that the sentence refers to one person's thoughts about a relationship with one other person, then the word "both" is not necessary, and actually is a bit confusing. For example if I say to another person "We are both married", that usually means that we are **not** married to each other, in contrast to the meaning of  "We are married".